# Extract a string between second and third underlines

Tags: python, regex

My data looks like this:

```
ABC_10_2007_06_14.txt
ABC_11_2008_07_14.txt
```

I would like to extract 2007 and 2008. What would be the regular expression for that? I tried below, but it is not working.

```
.*_.*_(.*)_.*_.*\..*
```

Comment: How about `r'(?:.*?_){2}(\d+)'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `?` operator:

```
_.*?_(.*?)_.*?
```

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'ABC_10_2007_06_14.txt'
>>> re.findall(r'_.*?_(.*?)_.*?', s)[0]
'2007'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
a = "ABC_10_2007_06_14.txt ABC_11_2008_07_14.txt"
obj = re.findall(r"_.*?_(\d+)_.*?_.*?",a)
print obj
```

This will extract `2007` as well as `2008` in list type object `obj`.